# Quickbooks Desktop php Library Issue in "ReceivePaymentToDepositQuery"

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have been using quickbooks desktop php library for about an year now. My basic workflow in current system is:

. Enqueue requests by making api calls.
. Import the qwc file in the connector and run. it will pull the enqueued requests from server, process them and return the response back to the server.

This is how my code base looks like:
https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php

By following above code base, i am able to query the invoices, customers, accounts, items.... etc. But my request for getting the list of undeposited payments is not working. I got the request xml from here:

https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Just select "ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq" from the dropdown, you will see the xml. I have also printed the final request xml that gets formed in logs. It looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?qbxml version="13.0"?>

<QBXML>

```
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">

    <ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq metaData="MetaDataAndResponseData">

        <IncludeRetElement>TxnLineID</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>TxnType</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>CustomerRef</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>TxnDate</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>RefNumber</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>Amount</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>CurrencyRef</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>ExchangeRate</IncludeRetElement>

        <IncludeRetElement>AmountInHomeCurrency</IncludeRetElement>

    </ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq>

</QBXMLMsgsRq>
```

</QBXML>

Everything looks good till this point. But the issue is that i am not getting the result back. It is not even giving any error detail which is more painful. It would be great if any of you can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Note: In above xml, i have tried both with and without <IncludeRetElement> tags. Didn't work in both cases.

As requested by @Keith in the comments i have added my code here:

```
function _quickbooks_ReceivePaymentToDeposit_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
```

{

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
<ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq metaData="MetaDataAndResponseData">
<IncludeRetElement>TxnLineID</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>TxnType</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>CustomerRef</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>TxnDate</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>RefNumber</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>Amount</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>CurrencyRef</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>ExchangeRate</IncludeRetElement>
<IncludeRetElement>AmountInHomeCurrency</IncludeRetElement>
</ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq>
</QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>';

return $xml;
```

}

function _quickbooks_ReceivePaymentToDeposit_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{

```
$Createdon = date('Ymd');
$file = "logs/$Createdon.txt";
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $myFile = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fclose($myFile);
}
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "\n\n" . date("h:i:sa") . "\n" . $xml . "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

}

Comment: It doesn't look like you've really put the time in to troubleshoot yourself yet, and you have not included enough information for us to help you. 

1. The code you posted doesn't even have anything at all in it about `ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq`. Please post your actual code. 
2. Post your Web Connector log file. 
3. Your request is not valid, and does _not_ match what is in the OSR. The OSR shows a `<?xml version="1.0" ...` header, and several other wrapper tags you are missing entirely.

Comment: Hi Keith, i have tried my best to resolve this issue. But unfortunately couldn't find anything, then only i decided to look for some help. Here are my answers to the points you made

1. I have updated my question to add the basic code, that gets executed. Rest structure is same as you have in your php library in "example_web_connector.php" file.


2. I could not find any option to upload the files here. Therefore i am sharing a link to the qwc log file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18cNsDWxcra-jAVqEOMgcwToJOKo5cNKm/view


3. I have updated those tags in the question, please check.

Comment: You should fix your code formatting. Also, re-post your logs after running in VERBOSE logging mode. http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#setting_the_web_connector_to_use_verbose_logging_mode

Comment: Hi @Keith, here is the link to the log file with VERBOSE loggin mode.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18cNsDWxcra-jAVqEOMgcwToJOKo5cNKm/view

I can see the response for query here. But still no error description on why is it not working properly.

Comment: OK, did you look at it? Check your PHP error log? Fix your code formatting in the post above yet?

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. It is working now. There was nothing in the php error log. I just added "define('QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_RECEIVEPAYMENTTODEPOSIT', 'ReceivePaymentToDepositQuery');" in "QuickBooks.php" file and it started working.

Thanks for the help. Just one more query regarding this. Do this "ReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq" support iteration ?  as i don't see these tags in the osr xml

Comment: If it's not in the OSR, it's not supported. You should figure out how to turn on your PHP error log.